# Javadoc issue package does not exist in java11

Tags: java, javadoc, java-11, maven-javadoc-plugin

Javadoc says package doesnt exist in all the imports. This same setup worked for Java1.8 but with java 11 it has this issue

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9:jar (attach-javadocs) on project esymac: MavenReportException: Error while creating archive:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - /home/JDK/com/SelfMonServiceLocator.java:23: error: package com does not exist
[ERROR] import com.SelfMonConstants;
[ERROR] ^

It was working in java1.8 properly with the same classes and pom.xml. But with java11 it fails to find packages.

Comment: Huh? I use them all the time, and they are [still documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/javadoc/javadoc-command.html#GUID-3051737B-FFF9-45F9-85D1-5F07D6703592__GUID-7FBFFF8D-BF22-41B3-A6D7-2A8D09B5EFF8) - where did you find that they have been removed?

Comment: Besides, javadoc does not stop generating documents when encountering an unknown or unsupported tag. So if “javadocs are not getting generated”, the reason surely isn’t that `@see` or `@link` were not supported anymore.

Comment: Javadoc says package doesnt exist in all the imports. This same setup worked for Java1.8 but with java 11 it has this issue 

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9:jar (attach-javadocs) on project esymac: MavenReportException: Error while creating archive:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - /home/JDK/com/SelfMonServiceLocator.java:23: error: package com does not exist
[ERROR] import com.SelfMonConstants;
[ERROR] ^

Comment: Please edit your question to describe the complete error logs with the information of what your setup is. Providing a reproducible example would be great.

Comment: The error clearly tells you that it has trouble finding some class. There can be many reason for this. It mentions nothing about `@see` or `@link` no longer being supported. Fix the problem that causes the classes to not be found and it'll continue to just work fine. In other words: the question as posted is based on faulty assumption and can't be answered, please edit the question and add the complete error message in the body.

Comment: The line that the error message is referring to seems to imply that you have a class in a package named just "com". Is this true?

Comment: Yes that is correct. It says package does not exist but i checked com package is present. It also contains SelfMonServiceLocator.java file in it.